# How to save user-entered data for next time app is opened?

Tags: android

I have multiple views that user-entered data can be stored in. I also have views that don't do anything except for decoration, like spaces and dividers.

How can I save everything on screen so that when the app closes and I go back in everything is as I left it?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states covers pretty much everything.

Comment: Have you looked into using [Shared Preferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences)?

Comment: @pappbence96 I am now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to persist data on Android-

- File Storage (Internal / External) : Ideal for storing big files(Photo / video etc)
- Shared Preferences : Ideal for storing text values(Configuration values)
- Database : Ideal for storing structured data (List of items etc)

For your use case, check out shared preferences.
Learn more about it from the [official android guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage)

Answer (score 0):

If you want users data to be persisted use below:
1. Shared preference if data is less 
2. Room database to store large data set